# How do I generate distortion coefficients for a generic fisheye lens given its HFOV and VFOV?

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I would like to emulate the optical behavior of a certain camera knowing only the following parameters:

- it is a fisheye lens
- focal length in mm
- sensor size (horizontal and vertical) in mm
- sensor resolution (horizontal and vertical) in pixels
- HFOV and VFOV in degrees or radians

My goal is to transform a set of 3D points in space into 2D points on the camera's sensor. It looks like [cv2.projectPoints()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#projectpoints) can do this, but it requires a set of [distortion coefficients](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html), K<sub>1</sub>, K<sub>2</sub>, P<sub>1</sub>, P<sub>2</sub>, etc.

Most people get these coefficients by calibrating using a real camera. I would like to work with a notional camera. One such example is for a GoPro, [a person](https://web.archive.org/web/20221007180827/https://www.theeminentcodfish.com/gopro-calibration/) found these values:

```
[[-2.57614020e-01, 8.77086999e-02, -2.56970803e-04, -5.93390389e-04, -1.52194091e-02]]
```

I haven't been able to find an explanation of these parameters w.r.t. the input variables I've listed, and I don't understand enough about optics to know how to generate them.

How do I generate the distortion coefficients needed to use `projectPoints()` for a notional fisheye lens?